# Could not find sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I am specifically intertested in #270. You can see it here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

I've downloaded the code, unzipped it and I'm in the auth-before directory.

I run bundle install and I get

`Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find sprockets-2.0.0.beta.10 in any of the sources`

I've tried fixing it my self and I've gotten this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sprockets (~> 2.0) ruby

    sass-rails (~> 3.1.0.rc) ruby depends on
      sprockets (2.0.0.beta.10)
```

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

# Asset template engines
gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

What should I do to resolve this?

***update:***

I followed the suggestion below and removed the version number from sass-rails. When I run the update command I get the following:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.1.0) ruby

    rails (= 3.1.0.rc4) ruby depends on
      railties (3.1.0.rc4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the version limitation on `sass-rails` from your Gemfile, then run

```
bundle update sprockets sass-rails
```

Both [sass-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-rails) and [sprockets](https://rubygems.org/gems/sprockets) have a stable release now.

Comment: see update. Can I just change it to 3.1? Or is there a better version number?

Comment: @NoahClark, make it `~>3.1.0` - that means '3.1.0 or any other higher minor version' - 3.1.1 will match, but 3.2.0 won't

Comment: yes. That's working but you don't have to remove sass-rails version in gem file in Rails 3.2. Just try "bundle update sprockets sass-rails" on your terminal.